# Which type of value in the object as parameter of function. Why do not have the compilation errors?

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, object, arrow-functions

I have gotten the next bunch of code.

```
const func: ( newState: { newState: number }) => void = ({ newState: newState }) => {
    console.log(newState);
}
```

For me, particularly interesting is the `({ newState: newState })` how is it work?
Why can I write `newState: newState` in this situation, and no compilation errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 const func: ( labeledParameter: { newState: number }) => void = ({ newState: test }) => {
    console.log(test);
}

func({newState: 12});
```

It's because the first newState is a label put on the parameters give to the function -> i renamed it labeledParameter in my sample

the object

```
{ newState: newState }
```

is an object with a property newState and as value a number

to call the function you should use

```
func({newState: 12});
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's understand by segregating the typescript and javascript portions in your code snippet.

**TypeScript Portion**

```
( newState: { newState: number }) => void
```

The portion above defines the **type** of the function which states that the function accepts an argument (which can be named anything, here it's named `newState`) that is an object with a key `newState` which is of type `number` and the [`void`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#void) return type states that the function returns nothing.

**JavaScript Portion**

```
({ newState: newState }) => {
  console.log(newState);
}
```

And the portion above is the function definition where the argument is [destructed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) in-place and the `newState` key has been aliased to `newState`, which is redundant, but works.

A more elaborate version of the above code snippet is as follows:

```
type Func = (newState: { newState: number }) => void

const func: Func = (arg) => {
    const { newState: renamed } = arg;
    console.log(renamed);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

const func: ( labeledParameter: { newState: number }) => void = ({ newState: test }) => {
console.log(test);
}

func({newState: 12});
It's because the first newState is a label put on the parameters give to the function -> i renamed it labeledParameter in my sample

the object

{ newState: newState }
is an object with a property newState and as value a number

to call the function you should use

func({newState: 12});

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).